# jquery placeholder while ajax loads dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have a 2 dropdowns, one with a list of countries and one with a list of states. When someone clicks a country, the state dropdown is changed to reflect the ones for that country.

The country dropdown is like this:

```
<select name="country" id="country" onChange = "states_dropdown(this, 0)">
  <option value="001" >United States</option>
  <option value="002" >Canada</option>
  <option value="003" >Mexico</option>
</select>
```

And the states/provinces like this:

```
<select name="state" id="state">
  <option value="00101" >Alabama</option>
  <option value="00102" >Alaska</option>
  <option value="00103" >Arizona</option>
</select>
```

Obviously, the states change when someone changes the country, with this code:

```
function state_box(country, user_id) {
   var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();

   if (xmlHttp == null) {
      alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
      return;
   }

   var url = relative_path + 'ajax/states.php';
   var action = url + '?country_id=' + country.value;

   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
         document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
      }
   };
   xmlHttp.open("GET", action, true);
   xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

This all works fine, but the actual problem is that while the server processes the request, the states of the currently selected or default country remain visible. So if someone clicks really fast, he could choose Mexico as the country and Alabama as the state.

The ajax/jquery script states.php that loads the states returns just the option values, that's all.

Is there a way to make it so that **while it's loading**, it would display:

```
<option value="">Please wait</option>
```

and maybe even make the entire box as "disabled" to prevent someone from selecting it?

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = '<option value="">Please wait</option>';`

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent xmlHttp.responseText from showing?

Comment: You'd do this before you make the ajax call.

Comment: Indeed, that works! If you make an answer, I will accept it :) Any way to make it disabled, too? If possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the dropdown to show a waiting option as the new data loads, you can place this before you make the ajax request.

```
document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = '<option value="">Please wait</option>';
```

You can also just disable the dropdown, the advantage of this is that it is reversable(in case the request didn't succeed)

```
document.getElementById('state').disabled = true;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById('state').disabled = false;
        if (this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I would personally to just disable the select dropdown, in case it doesn't work, unless you store the value of your select dropdown before changing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function state_box(country, user_id) {
   var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();

   if (xmlHttp == null) {
      alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
      return;
   }

   var url = relative_path + 'ajax/states.php';
   var action = url + '?country_id=' + country.value;
   var selectBox = document.getElementById('state'); // save the reference to the element

   selectBox.innerHTML = '<option value="">Please wait</option>';
   selectBox.disabled = true;    // disable the select

   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
          selectBox.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
          selectBox.disabled = false;  // enable the select
      }
   };
   xmlHttp.open("GET", action, true);
   xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

provided the `responseText` is something like this `<option value="00101">city 1</option><option value="00102">city 2</option><option value="00103">city 2</option>`

check out this fiddle for reference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/adityasharat/LhxtzgL9/)